# How to Hide Ribbon except when deving

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007 and creating an invoicing system for my parent's business.  When I'm developing in Access, I would like to be able to see the ribbon nav, and also the object nav over on the left.  When I push it out to them for their use, I would like to hide all of that junk.

Is there an easy way to enter an access DB as a "dev" giving my all of the options, but when opened by an end user, all they see are the forms that I have AutoExec'd to open when the database is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle the navigation pane, I use F11.  To toggle the ribbon, Ctrl+F1 --- but that minimizes the ribbon rather than hides it completely.

If you want to do similar with VBA code:

```
'hide the navigation pane
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide

'unhide the navigation pane
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True

'hide ribbon
Docmd.ShowToolBar "Ribbon",acToolBarNo

'unhide ribbon
Docmd.ShowToolBar "Ribbon",acToolBarYes
```

An easy way to distinguish between the development and production versions of your application is to place them in separate folders.

```
If CurrentProject.Path Like "*Dev*" Then
    'do what you want for development mode
Else
    'do what you want for production mode
End If
```

If that doesn't work for you, there are many alternatives.

A table where you store the status, retrieve the status at startup, and do your adjustments based on the status.

Same approach, but using a database property instead of a table.

A module variable which your code checks to determine the status.

Those are a few, but you can come up with plenty more if you're motivated.